# How to play audio file with postDelayed?

Tags: java, android

I am building a game that is like Simon says, there's a sequence that the use should repeat after with button changing colors and more...
I want to know how to play a sound when a button changing color ? what should I use ? 
I've tried to use Media player option but I don't know how to do that not in postDelayed that take care of my color shifting in the button . so if some one can help that will be great.

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(colors[2]);//purple Butttons[1]


                }
            }, 4000);
            final Handler handlerr = new Handler();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buttons[2].setBackgroundResource(colors1[2]);//purple Butttons[1]


                }
            }, 4200);
```

Comment: What specific problems did you have with `MediaPlayer`? Also, `SoundPool` might be more appropriate for your setup.

Comment: MediaPlayer dosen't work when I am trying to use it with PostDelayed and it crash when the app run. I'll try the sound pool .

Comment: Thank you very much it works!!